# If cell matches a text from other sheet, return value from adjacent cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have two sheets: one calculates income after expanses and the other holds costs for parts from which the income sheet hopefully take the data to calculate. I need the income sheet to fill the price for an item based on a match for the adjacent word with the other sheet. For example:

This is the income sheet, I need ROW D to check if the items in ROW C are in the parts cost sheet.

SHEET A (Income):

[image: Income]

If they do, I need ROW D to get the price of that part from the adjacent cell in the parts cost sheet:

SHEET B (Parts Cost):

[image: Parts Cost]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in `D2` and drag-to-fill up to `D6`:

```
=IF(C2="","",VLOOKUP(C2,'SHEET B'!$A$2:$B$6,2))
```

The last number `2` refers to the second column in the range `$A$2:$B$6`.

You may need minimal modification since your columns are oddly right-to-left.